# Pandas timedelta column convert hours and minutes to integer format

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I know there are similar questions posted, but not exactly lining up to my use case.

I have a pandas column of timedelta values :

```
0 days 10:46:22.000000000
```

That I would like to look like an integer:

```
10.46
```

Is there a simple way to do so by extracting hours and minutes?

Comment: By looking like an integer - do you mean it's a float... or it's a string formatted as HH.MM ?

Comment: it would be a float format of HH.MM @JonClements

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html

Comment: Would the data type actually **be** a float though... because 10.46 where 10 is the hours and 46 is the minutes wouldn't really make sense as 10.46, it'd be more like 10.77

Comment: @YOBEN_S Timedelta objects don't support that method though...

Comment: yes you're right, I'd like to make it 10.77

Comment: how are you creating the time delta values? why do you want it as a floating point value, whats the end goal here?

Comment: @Datanovice the conversion is because I need it to export that way to excel. I've done multiple calculations using timedelta in the background but need final product as the float

Comment: Ummm.... does `df['your_column].dt.total_seconds() / 3600` do what you want?

Comment: yes! i know it seems simple but I'm learning and couldn't find this solution . thank you for taking the time

Comment: @paranormaldist okie dokies - made that an answer then

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `Timedelta`s to seconds and divide by 3600:

```
s = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta('0 days 10:46:22.000000000'), pd.Timedelta('5 days 100:31:22.000000000')])

float_hours = s.dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Gives:

```
0     10.772778
1    220.522778
dtype: float64
```